# Micronaut @Value does not get the environmental variable when running native image

Tags: java, micronaut, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I've build a native image with graalvm and micronaut, but my native-image app cannot get the environmental variable using @Value annotation. When I try to run the app as jar, it works just fine.

```
@Singleton
public class WebComponentService {
    @Value("${config.adyen.merchantaccount}")
    private String merchantAccount;
}
```

This is the error I get

> Message: Error setting field value: No field 'merchantAccount' found for type: example.micronaut.getOriginKeys.WebComponentService
> Path Taken: new GetOriginKeysController([WebComponentService webComponentService])
> io.micronaut.context.exceptions.DependencyInjectionException: Failed to inject value for field [merchantAccount] of class: example.micronaut.getOriginKeys.WebComponentService

However, when I try to get the environmental variables like this, it works fine.

```
Map<String, String> environmentVars  = System.getenv();
String merchantAccount = environmentVars.get("CONFIG_ADYEN_MERCHANTACCOUNT");
```

This is how I run the native app

```
$ CONFIG_ADYEN_MERCHANTACCOUNT=CommercetoolsGmbHDE775 ./theNativeApp
```

Answer (score 0):

The key you have used here `@Value("${config.adyen.merchantaccount}")`
is different than `environmentVars.get("CONFIG_ADYEN_MERCHANTACCOUNT");`

Make sure they're the same

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How come it works with JAR? Can you explain? I suppose micronaut does support relaxed binding for @Value like Spring does. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding

Comment: Relaxed binding isn't available with ```@Value```. See [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4413) discussion

Comment: I udpated my code to use `@Value("${CONFIG_ADYEN_MERCHANTACCOUNT}")` and it still doesn't work. I don't think it's related to relaxed binding, since I built JAR from it and it works just fine. When I use that JAR to build a native-image, it stops working.